# Sqlite3 import file command via node child process execSync has no effect

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

In my node application, I do the following:

Imports:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
```

Then in code, I open a sqlite3 database via sqlite.open:

```
const db = await sqlite.open({filename: '/home/ubuntu/Trading/api/samples.db', driver: sqlite3.Database});
```

Create a table ticks:

```
await db.exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticks (timestamp INTEGER, price REAL)');
```

Trying to import a file containing many thousands of rows in format "123434;222.11":

```
execSync('sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/Trading/api/samples.db -separator ";" ".import /home/ubuntu/shared_tr_data2/ticks/tickdata.log.2020-05-12 ticks"')
```

The last step is executed without exceptions, but the table ticks contains no rows afterwards:

```
let tickCount = execSync(`sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/Trading/api/samples.db "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticks"`).toString();
```

=> returns 0.

Here is the thing, if I copy this line

sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/Trading/api/samples.db -separator ";" ".import /home/ubuntu/shared_tr_data2/ticks/tickdata.log.2020-05-12 ticks"

1:1 into an ubuntu shell it works fine, the table ticks contains the records afterwards.

Additionally I want to mention if I remove e.g. "-separator ";"" from the line, I get warnings from the import process that no separator can be found and respective columns will be filled with NULL => so that means the import does actually seem to do what it should.

But the result is an empty ticks table. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to close the db before the execSync calls.

If anybody knows a better explanation why this is so, you are welcome to share it :)